# cannot install language package in ubuntu18.04

Tags: language-support

I'm trying to install French support in Ubuntu 18.04.

In Language Support, i clicked "Install/Remove Languages" and ticked "French, then the error message popped out:

Failed to download package files.

Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-fr_67.0+build2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

What shall I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox has been updated to version 67.0.1. Try closing Firefox, check for updates, and then add French.

```
~$ apt-cache policy firefox-locale-fr
firefox-locale-fr:
     67.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        ...
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
```

Version 67.0.xxx is, indeed, unavailable.

Comment: thx. after upgrading firefox, it works now.